# Where I can check nebular 5-6 compatibility with angular version

Tags: angular, nebular

I am trying to use the Nebular chat UI component and begin to install the nebular library from install guidelines. I am using the Angular 8.1.3 version and have the same errors with installing by schematics add and manual install modules with npm.
First of all, I receive many errors from the library and resolve them by adding

```
"skipLibCheck": true,
```

to tsconfig.json file. But actually got new errors:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NbEvaIconsModule -> NbIconLibraries]:
```

StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NbEvaIconsModule -> NbIconLibraries]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for NbIconLibraries!
My question is: does nebular 6 support angular 8 version? Or where I can check compatibility versions? Maybe nebular 5 does, or which version of angular supported at all?
Other question, maybe I can resolve these errors, please suggest